# How can I stop the iPhone from buzzing when it is ringing?

Tags: iphone, ringtones

I finally found a nice ringtone for my iPhone but can barely hear it because the phone buzzes while ringing. How can I switch of the buzzing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

settings - sounds - and vibrate on ring to off!

Comment: +1 ... that's if you mean vibrating when you say "buzzing".  The other possibility is that your new ringtone somehow got buzzing included in it.

Comment: I guess that is it.